# International travel with pet: what about the first leg (United, THY)

Tags: air-travel, connecting-flights, united-airlines, turkish-airlines, pets

Since United and Turkish are both Star Alliance, I can buy the entire ticket from Turkish and fly from my small city to a big airport (such as ORD) with United, then to Turkey (or wherever) with Turkish.

I need to do this with a medium-sized dog.  If I make the arrangements with Turkish, does this imply that the first leg with United will be covered as well?  If United normally doesn't transport dogs domestically under the same rules (or at all) am I out of luck?

How does one typically fly with dogs with two airlines?

Edit: the dog will be pet cargo, it's too big to go under the seat.

Comment: Do you plan on having the dog travel with you in the cabin, or in the hold? Some airlines will not allow connections for pets in the hold, others will only allow connections when they are with the same airline. I'm quite convinced that contrary to luggage allowance, here it will be the most restrictive policy which will prevail.

Comment: @jcaron - hold. What you say makes sense - but people are getting pets to other countries somehow.  I know there's services out there that help out, maybe I have to go with one of those.  Or rent a car and drive to the major international airport...

Answer (score 1):

An incomplete but perhaps useful answer:  on [United's page concerning in-cabin pets](https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/animals/in-cabin.html), they note that

> United's in-cabin pet policy applies to flights operated by United and United Express® only. **For codeshare flights, please check the operating carrier’s in-cabin pet policy.  If you are traveling on multiple airlines, please check with each carrier individually to ensure acceptance.**  United can only accept your pet for flights operated by United and United Express.

(bolding mine)

There doesn't seem to be similar language on their pages concerning pets as cargo, but I wouldn't necessarily take that to mean the policy is different.  It's also possible that Turkish Airlines *will* guarantee that your pet will be able to travel on all code-share segments if you buy through them, even though United won't;  but that seems doubtful to me.